# Use of undeclared identifier 'CTRadioAccessTechnologyNR'

Tags: xcode, react-native

Errors when starting an xcode application
errors:

- Use of undeclared identifier 'CTRadioAccessTechnologyNRNSA'
- Use of undeclared identifier 'CTRadioAccessTechnologyNR'

[image][1]

nodejs, cocoapods, watchman installed

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

I also have meet this issue a day ago, and finally got fixed after installing Xcode version later than 12.0
You should install Xcode version later than 12.0

https://github.com/dcloudio/native-docs/issues/30